# Create clickable label on vector layer

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I remeber that in OpenLayers version 2 you could set an attribute for the label of the feature, so when it was clicked, resulted the same action as when you clicked the feature itself.

So either clicking the point or its label, that feature was considered clicked.

The code was `'labelSelect': true`

But now, in OpenLayers 3.9 I dont see that setting. Is there a way to make labels clickable?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to [forEachFeatureAtPixel](https://geoadmin.github.io/ol3/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel). I'm pretty sure that takes in account the label too.

Comment: link doesn't work any more

Comment: link fixed @MarcosJ.DJunior